# Trying to create user defined database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing, jdbc

```
public void create(String name) {
    create_name = name;
    try {
        getConnection();
        q = "create table ? (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15))";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(q);

        pst.setString(1, create_name);
        int j = pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(), "Table is Created");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(), "Table is not Created");
    }

}
```

Comment: did you get any error, did your table created, what is your question exactly ?

Comment: You cannot parameterize object identifiers like table names

Answer (score 1):

To create a table with `PrepapredStatement` this is not possible, because when you make

```
q= "create table ? (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15))";
```

So in reality it will execute this query here :

```
create table 'table_name' (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15))
```

and the `'table_name'` is forbidden when you create a table, so instead to that i suggest to play with your `PrepapredStatement` like this :

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("create table ? (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15))");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "table_name");

    System.out.println(preparedStatement.toString());
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    int i = st.executeUpdate(preparedStatement.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\""));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(), "Table is Created");        

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JDialog(), "Table is not Created");
}
```

The idea is simple when you prepare your Statement you will get the previous query you can get it like this `preparedStatement.toString()` so you can change the `''` in the start and in the end with `""` because `"` is allowed in oracle to [create a table with a name which contain spaces](http://www.kodyaz.com/oracle/plsql-double-quotes-for-space-in-table-name.aspx).